# \draw[] not working in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, draw

I would like to draw a vertical line in the plot, indicating the mode of the left gaussian.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, 
  domain=0:90, 
  samples=300,
  ymin=0,
  axis lines*=left, 
  xlabel=$x$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, 
  width=12cm,
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, 
  clip=false, 
  axis on top,
  grid = major,
  hide y axis,
  xtick distance=10
  ]

\addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(x, 45, 5)};
 \addplot [very thick,red!50!black] {gauss(x, 55, 5)};


\draw[dashed] (45,-10) -- (45,10);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However what I do get is the picture, but without the line. Why?[image: The picture I get]

Comment: Add `compat` option: `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`.

Comment: The coordinates in the axis do not correspond to the actual Ti*k*Z coordinates, so you have to tell Ti*k*Z that you are using the axis coordinate system (and reduce the `y` coordinate to fit in the graph: `\draw[dashed] (axis cs:45,0) -- (axis cs:45,0.08);`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik What would be the "TikZ coordinate system"?

Comment: @AlphaOmega The answer became too long for a comment so I posted as an answer (your question is a duplicate of the one linked, though).

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment:

When you `\draw(0,0)--(1,1);` the coordinates `(0,0)` and `(1,1)` are mapped to the Ti*k*Z coordinate system (I just invented this name).

When you use an `axis` environment, `pgfplots` maps the coordinate system of the axis to this Ti*k*Z coordinate system to draw. These two coordinate systems *can* concide, but they usually don't, and that's why you have to tell Ti*k*Z to use the `axis cs:` instead of its usual coordinate system. If you were using a `pgfplots` command, like `\addplot` inside an `axis` environment you wouldn't need to say that explicitly because that would be already assumed.

To see the difference, take this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [blue] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \draw [gray] (0,0) grid [step = 0.2] (1,1);
  \begin{axis}[
      grid = major,
    ]
    \addplot [red] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
    \draw [green] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:0,1);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

> [image]

The two lines produced with `\addplot` and `axis cs:` are correctly drawn in the axis and the coordinates map to the correct tick values. The blue line, however, is far off because the coordinate system is different. Notice that both the axis grid and the hand drawn Ti*k*Z grid have spacing of `0.2`.

You can, of course, force both coordinate systems to match. You have to tell `pgfplots` to use the `x` and `y` unit vectors equal to the ones used by Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    x = 1cm,% <-- Default
    y = 1cm,% <-- Default
  ]
  \draw [yellow] (-0.1,-0.1) -- (1.1,1.1); % A slightly larger one
  \draw [blue] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \draw [gray] (0,0) grid [step = 0.2] (1,1);
  \begin{axis}[
      grid = major,
      x = 1cm,% <-- same as TikZ's
      y = 1cm,% <-- same as TikZ's
      enlargelimits = false,
      font = \fontsize{2}{2},
    ]
    \addplot [red] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
    \draw [green] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:0,1);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

> [image]

Now both coordinate systems match. I used the `x` and `y` unit vectors equal to `1cm` each (the default in Ti*k*Z), but any other value goes. I also added `enlargelimits = false` and `font = \fontsize{2}{2}` to improve readability.

In your case, however, the `x` unit vector is much longer than `y` because the graph is `90` units wide and barely `0.1` high, so you'd need to adapt Ti*k*Z's coordinate system to match `pgfplots`', or the picture would be smashed into a line. But easier than messing with unit vectors is to tell Ti*k*Z which coordinate system to use to `\draw`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, 
  domain=0:90, 
  samples=300,
  ymin=0,
  axis lines*=left, 
  xlabel=$x$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, 
  width=12cm,
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, 
  clip=false, 
  axis on top,
  grid = major,
  hide y axis,
  xtick distance=10
  ]

\addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(x, 45, 5)};
\addplot [very thick,red!50!black] {gauss(x, 55, 5)};

\draw [dashed] (axis cs:45,0) -- (axis cs:45,0.08);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Or, as JouleV suggested, since `1.11` `pgfplots` already adjusts Ti*k*Z's `\draw` commands to use the `axis cs:` when inside an `axis` environment, so you have but to use:

```
\pgfplotsset{
  % compat = 1.11, %<-- At least 1.11
  compat = 1.16,
}
```

and then:

```
\draw [dashed] (45,0) -- (45,0.08);
```

the result is the same.